# positive root for exponential polynomial

Tags: exponential-polynomials

Suppose $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_n$ are algebraic numbers. $P_1(t),P_2(t),\cdots,P_n(t)$ are polynomials with algebraic coefficients.

The question is to whether the following question is decidable.
$$\sum_{i}^n P_i(t)\exp(\lambda_i t)$$
has a root $t_0>0$.

Comment: analytical or numerical?

Comment: The question is whether there's an algorithm saying whether there's a positive root, not to compute this root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all numbers are real, it is decidable. This follows, for example from the general result in the paper

Vorobʹev, N. N., Jr. Deciding the consistency of a system of inequalities...

https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4612-0441-1_33.

If complex numbers are allowed it is not clear to me what the answer is.
Chebotarev has a generalization of Sturm's theorem to functions
of the form $P(x,\cos x,\sin x)$ where $P$ is a polynomial, but I do not
know a reference for a general result with complex $\lambda_k$. I suspect it might be wrong: with complex $\lambda$ the question might be undecidable.